# DartEditor rename a property error

Tags: dart-editor

I'm trying to rename a property in a class and I get this error:

> element and references in SDK and external package will not be renamed

Now the code is a bit complex, but the property is just an SvgElement in my own class and it's not referenced outside it.

It's something like

```
class Abc {
   svg.ImageElement abcdef;
   Abc() {
       abcdef.setAttribute('x','0');
       //etc
   }
}
```